Is it possible to grey out instead of conditionally hide/show region display selector
Well I suppose the title says it all. I have 8 regions, but a couple are dependent on a value. However, because the order of the region selector changes depending on the value, I was wondering if it was possible to always show all regions, but simply greyed out so that they cannot be clicked if the condition is not met. With this the order and thus position of the regions won't change and thus there can always be clicked on the right region from memory instead of double checking the region name, because its position will change depending on the value if that makes any sense.
Thanks

Not out of the box - region display selector is just "on" or "off". The regions are rendered in the DOM and when you click a tab, that region is displayed and the others are hidden. If there is a serverside condition on a region that region will not be part of the DOM and the region display selector tab for that region is not rendered.

The simplest way to implement such a functionality would be to use JQuery statements in the dynamic action where you already decide which region is enabled/disabled.
RDS has the following DOM structure (supposedly given static IDs to regions)
<ul class="t-Tabs t-Tabs--simple a-Tabs">
  <li class="t-Tabs-item" id="tab1">...</li> 
  <li class="t-Tabs-item" id="tab2">...</li>
<ul>

In a dynamic action with the action "Execute Javascript Code", you can use a JQuery selector and add a style (conforming to your business logic of course):
$('#tab1').css('pointer-events', 'none');
// or vice versa: 
$('#tab1').css('pointer-events', 'unset');


In addition to this some logic would have to be applied to ensure the regions are not in the dom... a user with basic jquery knowledge can show a region that is not clickable with rds

Sorry, I am quite new to apex. Where would I put the  text? I have added a dynamic action and added the Javascript code. But when I add the server side condition, the region selector still disappears when the condition is met. Thanks in advance for your help
